# Overload Class Instance Variable

Tags: c++

I've been looking for this for a bit and haven't had any luck. May be that I'm searching for the wrong words, or perhaps it's an unusual request (Or simply not doable).

Regardless, my question: I want to be able to use an instance of a class... well, here's a very simple example:

```
class attribute
{
    float value;
    float min;
    float max;
}

attribute attr1;
attr1.value = 5.0f;
```

Now, basically, I want to use attr1 as if I'm calling

```
attr1.value
```

So when I, say,

```
std::cout << attr1 << std::endl;
```

It would print 5.0 (Or just 5).

Thanks!

Comment: You store `5.0f` in `attr1.value` and are wondering why you get it as a return value? Seriously?

Comment: Nope. Read again. I'm wanting to know how to display 5 (Or 5.0) by JUST using attr1, instead of attr1.value.

Comment: You have to override operator<< for ostream. You will find every you need on internet with this information

Comment: Overload the `<<` operator and round the return value to your liking would my way of doing that.

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't work if I didn't want to use it for cout << specifically. Let's say I had a parameter that expected a float. I'd want to pass in attr1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, attribute const& att)
{
    os << att.value;
    return os; // this is how you "chain" `<<`
}
```

Either permit `att.value` through `public`, `friend`ship, or write a function.

Another alternative would be to build a cast operator to `float`:

```
class attribute
{
    public:
    operator float() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    private:
    /*the rest of your class here*/
```

But this could introduce unexpected ambiguities.

Finally, if you want `attribute` to behave like a numeric type, then you can overload more operators as you see fit. For example, to overload `+=`, you could write

```
template<typename Y>
attribute& operator+=(const Y& p)
{
    value += p;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Sure. Is there a way to do it in such a way it works universally, though? Such as... passing in as a parameter and treating it as a float in that instance?

Comment: You mean a cast operator to `float`? (That might cause you trouble though).

Comment: Somewhat. Think of it like attr1 BECOMES attr1.value as far as the rest of the program is concerned. Obviously, attr1 is an instance of the attribute class. But I want it to pretend - masquerade as, if you prefer - it's the 'value' variable inside that class. But, of course, I still want to treat it as if it's a class variable to anything that doesn't require it to be a float.

Comment: @DrakeM. Imagine you actually manage to implement a general "overload" of a class instance to its instance variable: then how would we define access to methods and properties of that class instance? `attr.max` would try to access `attr.value.max` and so on.

Comment: Understood as a complication, but I suppose my question is... in the event it 'should' be a float, it should be a float. If that makes sense? If I pass the variable into a function that expects a float, if I print it out, if I add 5 to it... etc. I suppose the only way to handle that is to handle every overload, yep?

Comment: @DrakeM. You could use templates so you can get the operators out with less typing. I'll add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll tinker with these and see how it goes.

Comment: @DrakeM. I might add that it sounds as if you're looking for type inference in a strongly typed language: e.g. one which could allow say two (same-name) `value` properties of diff. types, e.g., `int` & `float`. In such a case, type of `attr.value` (and hence the actual member) would be _infered_ depending on its use, and template/generic functions could implemented for hand-to-hand use with this type inference. E.g. Swift is an example of such a language. I can't say, however, if this is somehow possibly in C++0x using `auto`, as C++ isn't my strong suit; perhaps some else can comment on this.

Comment: @Bathsheba Out of curiosity, what problems arise with overloading casting (Such as the float example)? Is it unreliable, or just confusing? Are there known bugs with it? Something else?